# WP7 Sample Using Tiles to navigate and re-order panorama items that are DataBound without removing the Pivot-Items?

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I am really confused here. I did read all the tips on how to navigate panorama items, searched all the forums and did come to a solution by removing all items, and re-adding them and setting the desired panorama item as selected item. This works really good. The problem is only, that i loose all data-bindings, when I remove the panorama-items from the panorama control. I was thinking about not to allow any navigation options, and to let the user only slide through the panorama-items, and not jumping to a specific item via tile. Currently I am stuck and don't know how to prevent data loss. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not recommended to move the panorama items around. If you need to add more information, the app should navigate to a new page. If you want the panorama to start on a different page (like the Picture Hub) you can do this by setting the DefaultItem of the Panorama. A good way to do this is to store the index of the item you want, then retrieve it later to get the item and then set the DefaultItem property.

```
// Store index
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["PanoramaIndex"] = MyPanorama.SelectedIndex;


...
// Get index and set
int index;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue("PanoramaIndex", out index);
object defaultItem = MyPanorama.Items[index];
MyPanorama.DefaultItem = defaultItem;
```

Comment: Hey Shawn thank you for this information. I Think I will remove the navigation tiles I have on the default page and I will add only informational content, and tiles to be attached to the start-page. And thank you for the additional code. I used the SelectedIndex property to set the PanoramaItem after coming back from tombstone. I think i "misused" the control. Thank you again for your help.